# Assembly (NASM)

Tags: string, input, binary, decimal

i dont know how to fix this error in my code

jdoodle.asm:70: error: label `input' inconsistently redefined jdoodle.asm:2: info: label` input' originally defined here
jdoodle.asm:71: error: label `binary' inconsistently redefined jdoodle.asm:3: info: label` binary' originally defined here
jdoodle.asm:73: error: label `newline' inconsistently redefined jdoodle.asm:4: info: label` newline' originally defined here
ld: cannot find *.o: No such file or directory

The program must accept either positive or negative input strings in decimal format.
The input string must be typed in by the user during the program execution.
The program must convert the input string into binary form.
The binary form must be displayed on the next line.
The program must continuously ask for an input string from the user.
The program must stop executing when the user key-in zero(0) as an input string.

```
section .data
    input db 16 DUP ('$')   ; Buffer to store input string
    binary db 16 DUP ('$')  ; Buffer to store binary form of input string
    newline db 0Ah, 0       ; Newline character for displaying binary

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Display prompt message
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, prompt
    mov edx, prompt_len
    int 0x80

input_loop:
    ; Read input string
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 16
    int 0x80

    ; Check if input is zero
    cmp byte [input], '0'
    je stop_execution

    xor ecx, ecx           ; Clear ECX register

convert_loop:
    mov al, byte [input+1+ecx]
    sub al, '0'
    mov bl, al
    mov al, 2
    mul bl
    add al, '0'
    mov byte [binary+ecx], al
    inc ecx
    cmp byte [input+1+ecx], 0
    jne convert_loop

    ; Display binary form of input string
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, binary
    mov edx, ecx_len
    int 0x80

    ; Display newline
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, newline
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    jmp input_loop

stop_execution:
    ; Terminate program
    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80

section .data
    prompt db 'Enter a decimal number (0 to exit): '
    prompt_len equ $-prompt

section .bss
    input resb 16
    binary resb 16
    ecx_len equ $-binary
    newline resb 2
```